# openssl: verify w/out decrypting?

Tags: openssl

Given an openssl-encrypted and signed message, is there any way to verify the signature without decrypting the message?  Is the signature extractable from the encrypted content?

Comment: is the signature created based on the clear-text?

Answer (score 0):

If the message is Encrypted and then signed, you can verify the signature without decrypting the message. Signature must be part of message otherwise, there would be no meaning of signature.

For the format such as PKCS #7, you can extract the signature.